# Select text (content) instead of cell with NSCell

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsoutlineview, nscell

I'm currently working in a project with a NSOutlineView...

I use, of course, NSCell(s) and I need to let the ability to select text inside the cell...
Or at least... prevent the selection (and highlight) of the cells...

I search all options on IB, but can't found the right one...

**Is there a way, programmatically or not, to prevent selection/highlighting of cell, nor let user select cell content ?**

Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not much NSCell related, maybe you're looking to implementing `outlineView:shouldSelectItem:` in your delegate.

On the NSCell, `setEnabled:NO`, may help too. From the documentation:

`setEnabled:(BOOL)flag`

*The text of disabled cells is changed to gray. If a cell is disabled, it cannot be highlighted, does not support mouse tracking (and thus cannot participate in target/action functionality), and cannot be edited. However, you can still alter many attributes of a disabled cell programmatically. (The setState: method, for instance, still works.)*

Comment: Thanks :) I thinks it's the right way :) But what about selecting text in cells ?

Comment: Updated the answer, maybe it's what you need :P

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

You could also try overriding highlightSelectionInClipRect:, but I'm not totally sure this will work.

Comment: Except it's for iOS and UITableViewCell :) I'm talking about NSCell in Mac OS :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a quick example like the outline view below. There are 3 columns: `firstName`, `lastName`, and `fullName`.

[image]

In this particular example, let's say we want to only allow `firstName` and `lastName` to be editable while `fullName` (which is potentially derived from `firstName` and `lastName`) is not. You could set this up in Interface Builder by checking or unchecking the editable checkbox for the table column. To do that, click 3 times on one of the table columns (not the header, but inside the outline view); this first selects the `NSScrollView`, then the `NSOutlineView`, then an `NSTableColumn`:
[image]

You'd set the attributes like the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

That provides a start by setting a default editable value for the entire column. If you need more control over whether a particular row's item value should be editable or not, you can use the `outlineView:shouldEditTableColumn:item:` delegate method:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark <NSOutlineViewDelegate>

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)anOutlineView
    shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
               item:(id)item {

    if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"firstName"] ||
        [[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"lastName"]) {

        return YES;

    } else if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"fullName"]) {

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

If you want to control whether a particular row in the outline view is selectable (for example, you could prevent selection of a group item), you can use `outlineView:shouldSelectItem:`.

```
 - (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)anOutlineView shouldSelectItem:(id)item {
    // if self knows whether it should be selected
    // call its fictional isItemSelectable:method:

    if ([self isItemSelectable:item]) {
        return YES;
    }

    /* if the item itself knows know whether it should be selectable
     call the item's fictional isSelectable method. Here we
     are assuming that all items are of a fictional
      MDModelItem class and we cast `item` to (MDModelItem *)
      to prevent compiler warning */

    if ([(MDModelItem *)item isSelectable]) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not my problem, I don't want cells to be editable or selectable, I want **cells content** to be selectable... i.e. a cell containing "abcd", I want to be able to select abc (like a text zone) etc...